# Looking for a PHP class to parse an access.log file

Tags: php, apache, logging

Let's say I have an Apache Web server, with the default access.log file for a website. I'm looking for a PHP class to dissect it and give me info. Better than that, I'd love a PHP class that would simply dissect the following line (as an example):

```
123.125.66.111 - - [19/Aug/2010:17:21:23 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 409 "-" "Baiduspider+(+http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm)"
```

Any ideas? thx in advance

Comment: What are you doing with the data once you parse it?

Comment: Thanks Ish Kumar, for the life of me, I couldn't find one. I did some searching and still couldn't. Thx man.

Comment: @Ish Kumar This is a Q&A site about programming. This question is on topic and doesn't duplicate another, so it is welcome. If we only allow questions that Google doesn't answer, we won't get many questions at all :) Sometimes, it's hard to figure out what to search _for_.

Answer (score 3):

if you notice, the access log is not much different from a CSV,
especially if you are using tab as separator, pretty sure [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) fit the shoe

Answer (score 1):

This is from what Ish Kumar said:

> http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/012103.php3

Also, his search was a  good one:

> http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+parse+log+files

Comment: Err, a more focused search would be [http://www.google.com/search?q=php+parse+apache+access+log](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+parse+apache+access+log) or [http://www.google.com/q=how+can+i+parse+apache+log+files+with+php](http://www.google.com/q=how+can+i+parse+apache+log+files+with+php) and this search has a relevant result : [Class: Apache log parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2596-PHP-Parse-Apache-log-files-in-the-common-log-format.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is an old symfony plugin buth the classes should be usable anywhere else:
http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/tmApacheLogParserPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing with it and how much data is in the log, why not loop through it, split by a space and do what you need to do in the body of the loop? You haven't said what you are doing with the data.

Comment: Because the example line that I gave is splittable by spaces, however, Regex was going to be needed. I wanted to see if someone already did that (don't re-invent the wheel). Why do I need it? Well, to see who's checking out my website. Analytics, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) (look at the [demo](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/#DEMO) and the [features](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/#FEATURES))? My Webhoster has awstats installed and I am quite happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Other PHP based solutions that are still maintained:

- https://github.com/kassner/log-parser
- http://pimpmylog.com/

And if you are into Matomo/Piwik, you can import the logs (python required)

- https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-log-analytics