# parse a log file and store in a array using php

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, logging

I am trying to parse a log file and store it in an array. New information is added to it every 1 hour (cronjob) and I want to make sure that after my script queries the DB only if I get new information(hostname) then send out an email otherwise we should not send out the email. I have the log file in the follwing format:

```
Oct 31 13:45:01 Monitoring [info] Hostname : abc@abc.com
Oct 31 13:45:01 Monitoring [info] A count : 2195073
Oct 31 13:45:01 Monitoring [info] B count : 2191572
Oct 31 13:50:02 Monitoring [info] Hostname : abc@abc.com
Oct 31 13:50:02 Monitoring [info] A count : 2195073
Oct 31 13:50:02 Monitoring [info] B count : 2191572
```

I am looking to compare the hostname only and based on that comparison/logic will decide to send the email alert. Hence want to parse the above log file and store it in an array to perform the above action. I will have to create a new function under a class to parse the log file.

Can someone please help me out on how to create a function to parse the above log file ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Might need a little more to go on here; what have you tried? You're essentially just taking each line and parsing it for what you want. There are tons of log parsers available.

[Looking for a PHP class to parse an access.log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662725/looking-for-a-php-class-to-parse-an-access-log-file)

Comment: I had tried one method but it was like parsing a simple log file with just commas as separators. For the above log file I guess I would have to use regex to create array for each hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you have log like this example, try :

```
    $str = "Oct 31 13:45:01 Monitoring [info] Hostname : abc@abc.com";

    $pos = strpos($str, 'Hostname');
    if($pos !== null){  
        echo substr($str, $pos+11); // hostname 
    }
```